# How to get kivy to set its defaults in the Config at runtime?

Tags: python, kivy, default, configparser

How can I tell Kivy to update a given Config with its default values at runtime?

I have a "reset settings to defaults" button in my app that deletes all of the entries in my [Kivy Config](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.config.html), including in the `[kivy]` section.

```
# delete all the options saved to the config file
sections = ['kivy','myapp','etc']
   for section in sections:
      for key in Config[section]:
         Config.remove_option( section, key )

# write-out the changes to the .ini file
Config.write()
```

After the above commands execute, I'm left with an empty `[kivy]` section in my .ini file, as desired.

The problem is that I'm having a `NoOptionError` later in my code that's expecting the `default_font` option in the Kivy Config

```
configparser.NoOptionError: No option 'default_font' in section: 'kivy
```

After the above code wipes away any config options in the `[kivy]` section of my .ini file, how can I tell Kivy to repopulate it with the defaults?

When I restart the app, Kivy does repopulate the `[kivy]` section of my .ini file as desired. And I can see that the code that does that is located here:

- https://github.com/kivy/kivy/blob/c492a33f8cf79e89ea7240690feb5f6d25b08389/kivy/config.py#L902-L908

```
     elif version == 16:
         Config.setdefault('kivy', 'default_font', [
             'Roboto',
             'data/fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf',
             'data/fonts/Roboto-Italic.ttf',
             'data/fonts/Roboto-Bold.ttf',
             'data/fonts/Roboto-BoldItalic.ttf'])
```

But how can I execute the above kivy code at runtime so that it updates my Config with the defaults without having to restart the app?

> **Note** I'm aware that I can manually make my own `build_config()` function and call `Config.setdefaults('kivy', {...})` where I type the default values myself in the dictionary. **That's *not* what I'm asking for**. I'm asking how to call the above code that's part of kivy, so the code is not redundant and is future-proof.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think that changing your `Config` defaults will have any effect on your currently running `App` if you change them as you describe. You can force reset by just having your `Button` remove the default `config.ini`. The path to the default `config.ini` is in `Config.filename`. The next time any `kivy` app is started, the default will be restored.

Another option is to not use `Config.write()` at all (that just saves the current settings to the `ini` file and is not necessary when just changing the settings for the current `App`). Then just do a `Config.read(Config.filename)` to restore the settings that are still in the `ini` file.

Comment: Can you please update your answer with some actual code?

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't answer the question. The question is specifically asking about updating it during runtime. And, yes, updating it during runtime does fix the bug.

Comment: What is the bug that is fixed?

Comment: `NoOptionError` is fixed when updating the Config during runtime. Please read the OP.

Comment: That is not a bug. That is the result of your eliminating the `default_font` setting. Rather than eliminating the settings, just remove the file.

Comment: This is not a bug in kivy. This *is* a bug in my app. It is fixed by calling `Config.setdefaults('kivy', {...})` inside my App's `build_config()` using the snippet copied from `kivy/config.py`. Please read the OP.